# how authenticate private channel with echo server in laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I am trying to implement WebSocket using laravel  echo server, and I have a private channel , but I am not able  to have authenticated users this is my broadcast service provider

```
 public function boot()
    {
 
        Broadcast::routes([
            "middleware" => ['api','auth:api'],
 
        ]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

this is my bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://127.0.0.1:6001',
   authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth",
    csrfToken: token

});
```

this my event code

```
class UserOnline implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('chat');
    }
}
```

this is my  routes/channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('presence-chat', function ($user) {
    return true; //replace with suitable auth check here
});
Broadcast::channel('chat', function (User $user) {
    return true;
});
```

this is how I am listening to the event

```
   Echo.join('chat')
            .joining((user) => {
                axios.put('/api/user/'+ user.id +'/online', {});
            });
```

but all I am getting is this

> [4:42:50 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost
> [4:42:50 PM] - Sending auth request to:
> http://localhost/broadcasting/auth
>
> [4:42:50 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost
> [4:42:50 PM] - Sending auth request to:
> http://localhost/broadcasting/auth
>
> ⚠ [4:42:51 PM] - lNRPHJfHfhzrp252AAAJ could not be authenticated to
> private-user.1 {"message":"Unauthenticated."} Client can not be
> authenticated, got HTTP status 401 ⚠ [4:42:51 PM] -
> lNRPHJfHfhzrp252AAAJ could not be authenticated to presence-chat
> {"message":"Unauthenticated."} Client can not be authenticated, got
> HTTP status 401

please what is my wrong and where is my error ? I was  wasting couple of days  searching for this

Answer (score 0):

I set localhost and ip and APP_URL and host to `0.0.0.0` then I send CSRF token. Sometimes it seems they have different destination that why I set them in one (`0.0.0.0`) and it works !

and csrf like this:

```
window.Echo = new MyEcho({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: '0.0.0.0:6001', // this is laravel-echo-server host
    auth:{
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
    }}

});
```